# Why self not working on the eloquent query (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, self, eloquent

My repository code is like this :

```
public function getStatusList()
{
    $query = UsersBank::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                      ->where('status', '=', 1)
                      ->count();
    dd($query);               
}
```

The result of dd($query) = 1, It's true

But I try self like this :

```
public function getStatusList()
{
    $query = self::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                      ->where('status', '=', 1)
                      ->count();
    dd($query);               
}
```

The result of dd($query) = 4, It's false

Why when using self, the result is not correct?

Comment: self only works for static classes/properties try $this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self only works for static classes/properties I assume yours is not. Use $this instead.

Like this

```
$query = $this->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
              ->where('status', '=', 1)
              ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

If you use static method you can use only self::staticMethod(); or namespace.

If you use non-static method you can use $this->method();